# MySQL - Match and replace text in a column from another table during SELECT

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table that has a column that can contain a reference to another table. Here is an example of the value.

**Descriptions table**:

```
This cards effect that adds an "Ancient Gear" monster or <<7683>> from your Deck to your hand is a Trigger Effect. (It does not target.)
```

The reference in this instance is: `<<7683>>`

**ID Match table**:

```
'7683', 'Geartown'
```

I'm attempting to do a simple `SELECT * FROM descriptions` but the output needs to have the matching name in it instead of the reference (`<<7683>>` in this example).

So my expected output is:

```
This cards effect that adds an "Ancient Gear" monster or Geartown from your Deck to your hand is a Trigger Effect. (It does not target.)
```

I'll have roughly 3000 of these references when I do my `SELECT *`

I've created a fiddle with exact example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33a03a/3/0

I'm kind of thinking it would end up something like this:

```
SELECT 
     cd.name,
     cd.description 
FROM `descriptions` cd
JOIN `idmatch` t on t.name REGEXP CONCAT('^', cd.description , 'regex match?')
```

EDIT: MySQL version 5.7.29

Comment: Can there be more than one reference in a description e.g. `This <<1234> does <4567>>`?

Comment: Yes there can be!

Comment: If your MySQL version is 5.x that makes it pretty tricky.

Comment: Yeah it's 5.7.29. I'm also thinking of rerunning my script and doing this through PHP instead and using PHP to update the value in the table directly. Maybe better?

Comment: I think that would be a better solution. It's very hard to extract multiple pieces of information out of a string in MySQL 5.x and replace them. It can be done for one piece (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33a03a/17) but is messy.

Comment: No problem at all! Thanks for the feedback! I'll run this through PHP instead and just update the value in the column.